# Bisection search code doesnt work

Tags: python, bisection

Could you explain where i'm going wrong with this code? I want to do a bisection search which takes input number and repeats bisection search until it finds the same number as input and prints out various statements.

```
num =int( input("Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"))
maximum = num
minimum = 0
average = (minimum+maximum)/2.0

while(average<num):
 print ("Is your secret number ", +average, "?")  
 cond = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")

 if( cond == "h"):
    maximum = minimum
    minimum = 0
 elif(cond == "l"):
    minimum = maximum
    maximum = 100
 elif(cond == "c"): 
    print("Game over. Your secret number was: ", +average)
    break
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run this program?

Comment: You never update `average` or `num`, so how does the loop exit other than `cond == 'c'`? In otherwords, you never "divide" your search space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to input a guess. You are always going to start at the mid-point of your range.

So, instead, *wait* for the user to think of a number, **then** guess.

```
import time

minimum = 0
maximum = 100
print("Please think of a number between {} and {}!".format(minimum, maximum))
time.sleep(3)

average = (minimum + maximum)/2.0

while(True):
    print ("Is your secret number ", +average, "?")  
    cond = input("Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low.Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly.")
```

Second problem, you need to "divide" your search space. If the guess is too high, set that guess as the maximum, if too low, set that as the minimum. No need to set the other value in either case; it stays the same.

```
    if( cond == "h"):
        maximum = average
    elif(cond == "l"):
        minimum = average
    elif(cond == "c"): 
        print("Game over. Your secret number was: ", +average)
        break
```

And lastly, you need to update `average` each time through the loop to generate a new guess.

```
    average = (minimum + maximum) / 2.0
```

Comment: No sure you should be dividing by a float.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Probably not, but it just makes the loop prompt for a really long time

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for clearing that out. It was very well put.

Comment: You may show your thanks by accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it